# An alternative way to construct a long np.array from list - Google Colab RAM crash

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a deep learning project with images as input. Because of some other requirements, I cannot load the images from a folder on a go and need to do it beforehand.

I struggle with loading all the images into a numpy array as there are quite a few of them. Namely, because of the length of the list, I often run out of the 25 GB RAM on Google Colab. I know that lists are super space-expensive, while numpy arrays are not. However, it is pain to be loading images directly into a numpy array. So, I came with sort of a workaround where I only load 1000 images into a list at a time, turn that into a numpy array and append that. It all seems to work extremely well, until about the ninth interaction when RAM usage jumps from circa 3GB to 25GB and it all crushes.

I am using the following code:

```
# Get images
def get_images(folder):
    imgsl = []
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        imgsl.append(img_to_array(load_img(folder + filename)))
        i += 1
        if i == 19:
            imgs = np.array(imgsl, dtype=float)
            imgsl = []
        if i%1000 == 0:
            i = 20
            imgst = np.array(imgsl, dtype=float)
            imgsl = []
            imgs = np.append(imgs, imgst, axis = 0)
            print('Thousand images processed!')
            print('len: imgls: ', len(imgsl))
            print('imgs shape: ', imgs.shape)
    #imgs = np.array(imgs, dtype=float)
    imgst = np.array(imgsl, dtype=float)
    imgsl = []
    imgs = np.append(imgs, imgst, axis = 0)
    return imgs
```

and get the expected outcome until it crashes:

```
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (1000, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (1980, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (2960, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (3940, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (4920, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (5900, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (6880, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (7860, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (8840, 224, 224, 3)
Thousand images processed!
len: imgls:  0
imgs shape:  (9820, 224, 224, 3)
```

Any idea what's going on? Or suggestions on fixing it?
Thanks!

Comment: `np.append` with `axis` is just a call to `np.concatenate`. Using `concatenate` once on a whole list of arrays is better that doing it iteratively.  In any case it's fairly easy to estimate the memory of an array.  Or look at the `nbytes` attribute.

Comment: That last displayed array takes up 12GB.  To make the next you need space for that plus an additional 13GB.

Answer (score 0):

> I struggle with loading all the images into a numpy array as there are quite a few of them

This is not generally reasonable to do that and can cause a high memory footprint like the one you saw.

> I know that lists are super space-expensive, while numpy arrays are not.

This is not true if the list contains Numpy array. The overhead of a list is a 8-byte reference to an in-memory CPython object per item and a small header per list (<100 bytes) on 64-bit platforms. Assuming your image are big, this overhead is negligible. However, using list of list of list to store N images would be very expensive (as each integer/float value would be stored in a separate CPython object taking dozens of bytes in addition to the references).

> it is pain to be loading images directly into a numpy array.

It depends of the library used to load them. Some libraries like OpenCV gives you directly Numpy arrays (which is very convenient by the way).

> I came with sort of a workaround where I only load 1000 images into a list at a time

Good decision although it still take a significant space (smaller batches are certainly more reasonable).

> It all seems to work extremely well, until about the ninth interaction when RAM usage jumps from circa 3GB to 25GB and it all crushes.

One problem is that you use `np.append` which creates a new array every time. Each array is built from the previous one so you actually need at least 2 of them. This can also cause memory fragmentation resulting to a higher memory footprint. You should append the items into a list and then concatenate the arrays (eg. with `np.concatenate` or alternative functions like `np.vstack` / `np.hstack`).

Another problem is `np.array(imgsl, dtype=float)` which is certainly the biggest one. Indeed, images are generally encoded using 1 byte per component (eg. 3 or 4 per pixel). The `float` type here means the array items are 64-bit floats. Thus, the resulting array takes 8 bytes per component which is not reasonable (both in space and time efficiency). A small improvement is to use 32-bit float (`np.float32`). You could try the `np.float16` type so to reduce even further the memory footprint. Still, it will take 2 times more space than the `uint8`/`int8`-based array, not to mention the two array should be stored in memory simultaneously to do the conversion. A better approach is to **preallocate the output array and fill it on the fly in the loop**.

Comment: Using `np.float32` and `np.concatenate` helped. I also overwrote `imgslt` with an empty list immediately after using it - not entirely sure why but it helps. I think that going onward with the project, I will try to redo the whole image loading process but for the time being the fixes seem to work!